# Tail Wing Dented—Is it safe to fly?

Tags: aircraft-design, safety

I’m sitting in the lounge waiting to board this flight. Saw a dent in the attachment of tail wing to the body. Is this common?[image]

Also I could be wrong and it is part of the design of the airplane.

Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: Related: [Why is the horizontal stabilizer root interface designed this way?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/34053/1696)

Comment: Thank you @fooot. Will read more into the design choice. Thanks!

Comment: Technically, this is called an adjustable stabilizer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stabilator

Comment: Although the tail wing wasn't dented in this case, it would have been interesting if someone had answered the title question. IF it were dented, would it be safe to fly?

Comment: @Cloud no, we don't answer hypothetical questions.

Comment: @Cloud depends on [how and where its dented](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/37759/what-are-the-consequences-of-hail-damage-to-a-small-ga-plane)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The [aircraft in question is an Embraer ERJ 175](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/N615CZ) the "dent" allows the [tail trim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stabilizer_(aeronautics)) to operate properly you can see it more clearly in this picture.

[image]

([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Trimmable_horizontal_stabiliser.JPG))

Comment: So why in the OP was the trim seamingly set to hard 'up'? (Before takeoff)? I would inform the pilot.

Comment: @Cloud no, you would not inform them, because they have checklists to run (i.e., they know the setting) and they don't care about the setting on ground standing still at the gate.

Comment: @Cloud Unless I'm aware of 1) a checklist for this particular type and operator that requires the trim to be set to zero after landing, _and_, 2) that no walkaround was performed (in which case the pilot would surely notice), _and_ 3) that the current trim is outside the allowable takeoff trim range with the to be loaded weight, _and_ 4) that the problem has not been resolved with the before-takeoff checklist completed; I would personally never bother a pilot with this. You're more likely to distract a pilot than fix something covered by checklists and procedures.

Comment: @Cloud Would you also inform the pilot that likely, the flaps are not set for takeoff, or the cargo door not secured open, or the engines are shut down, or there are loose objects immediately in front of the engine intake, or or or ...? I've said it before, and I'll say it again: at some point, *as passengers*, we just have to accept that the professionals paid to do a job know how to do their job. Yes, even professionals sometimes make mistakes, but that doesn't mean that (a) people don't learn from those mistakes, and (b) any given professional will make a mistake the one time you fly.

Answer (score 17):

Looking closely at the photo, that's an Embraer 175.  I Googled other photos of the same model aircraft, and all of them have a similar flat surface.  It appears to be a flat designed into the aft fuselage to accommodate trimming by moving the entire stabilizer ("tail wing") up and down at the leading edge.

Comment: Thank you @Zeiss Ikon. I see the Embraer 175 printed now that you mention it.

Comment: 737's have the same thing.